# softhsm v2 vs. Utimaco simulator

Tags: python, docker, pkcs#11, hsm, softhsm

I need to choose an HSM simulator to manage my keys.
Could you please help me choose between `softhsm v2` and `Utimaco` simulator?

Ideal would be that the simulator is dockerized.
I also would like to develop a Python library using `PKCS#11` to manage keys in the chosen `HSM`.

Comment: The Utimaco HSM simulator end user agreement does not allow production use.  Using it this way violates said agreement, so that answers your question.  Use softhsm.

Comment: @rip - I'm curious...what is it that the OP wants to do that would violate the Utimaco 
 EULA?

Comment: SecurityServer/CryptoServer EULA states that the Simulator may not be used in production environments.  OP did not state anywhere "for testing" or "to see how" or "to figure out".  The OP says, "I need an HSM to manage my keys", can only be assume s/he means production keys.